# Increasing a Column value by a % range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2012. The following query works great:

```
SELECT TOP 300 [ObjectID], [tbh_Objects].Title, [Discount], [tbh_Section].Title
FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] 
INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] ON tbh_Objects.SectionID = tbh_Section.SectionID 
ORDER BY tbh_Objects.AddedDate DESC
```

I want to fire a query which increases the discount value to a random % in the range of 5-10 for all 300 rows at once. So for eg: If DIscount of ObjectID=500 is 30, and the random value between 5 and 10 is "6", I want it to become 30+6%of30 for ObjectID=500.

Similarly for Object ID=230, let's say discount is 20 and the random value is 8, I want it as 20+8%of20.

The end result of the Discount **should always be a whole number** and not a decimal, so automatically rounds off.

Is this possible in SQL Server? How?

Comment: `select 5 + abs(cast(cast(newid() as binary(8)) as bigint)) % 1000000000 / 166666667`

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it. It also needed `abs()` to make sure the random value is positive.

Comment: `SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 5` is also an option

Comment: I thought about `checksum()`. Since it returns an `int` it's easier to just use that and I don't think there's an issue with randomness either.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I want this for 300 rows. Where have you taken the Discount column while doing the calculation? Also how do I do this using an UPDATE command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need random integers and a `Modulus (%)` operator. A possible approach to generate a random integers is using a combination of `NEWID()` and `CHECKSUM()` functions. The following simplified example is a possible solution to your problem:

```
SELECT 
   Discount,
   RandomPercent,
   CONVERT(int, (Discount * (100.0 + RandomPercent) / 100)) AS NewDiscount
FROM (
   SELECT Discount, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 5) AS RandomPercent
   FROM (VALUES (30), (20), (50), (70), (11), (21), (13), (15), (1), (6)) v (Discount)
) t
```

Result:

```
Discount RandomPercent NewDiscount
----------------------------------
30        7            32
20        5            21
50        6            53
70        10           77
11        9            11
21        9            22
13        8            14
15        10           16
1         6            1
6         5            6
```

If you need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
;WITH UpdateCTE AS ( 
   SELECT TOP 300 o.[Discount]
   FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] o
   INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] s ON o.SectionID = s.SectionID 
   ORDER BY o.AddedDate DESC
) 
UPDATE UpdateCTE 
SET [Discount] = CONVERT(int, (o.[Discount] * (100.0 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 5)) / 100))
```

If you want to round the new discounts before the integer conversion, use `ROUND()`:

```
SET [Discount] = CONVERT(
   int, 
   ROUND(o.[Discount] * (100.0 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 5)) / 100, 0)
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you also show me how to do this in an UPDATE statement? I want to Update the table with 300 rows at once and update the DISCOUNT value with Newdiscount value.

Comment: When I use this query, I get a squiggly under UpdateCTE saying that "Title was specified multiple times for UpdateCTE'. Any clues?

Comment: @CuriousDev This is because you have two `Title` columns in the CTE. Remove them, if you want to update only the `Discount` column, and the error will disapear.

Comment: One last query. Instead of selecting TOP 300, I want to be able to select using a range of Object ID. So say UPDATE rows where OBJECT ID is in Between 200 and 300. How can I update this query to reflect this?

Comment: @CuriousDev 1) Use the appropriate `WHERE` clause in the `UpdateCTE`, something like `WHERE ObjectID BETWEEN 200 AND 300` 2) Remove the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` clauses. That should be enough.

Comment: Does this look ok to you? 
;WITH UpdateCTE AS ( 
   SELECT o.[Discount]
   FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] o
   INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] s ON o.SectionID = s.SectionID 
   WHERE ObjectID BETWEEN 200 and 300
) 
UPDATE UpdateCTE 
SET [Discount] = CONVERT(int, (o.[Discount] * (100.0 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 5)) / 100))

Comment: @CuriousDev Seems OK. only use the appropriate alias (`o` or `t`) for the `ObjectID` column.